# Eclipse Error: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, fatal-error

I tried to run my app, but it is crashing before reaching the onCreate() method. I'm new to android and eclipse, so i do not even know where to start searching for the error.

That's the Error Message form LogCat:

```
 11-22 21:06:59.787: WARN/dalvikvm(433): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.HelloActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:146)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at com.example.app.HelloActivity.<init>(HelloActivity.java:51)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
    11-22 21:07:01.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(433):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Well... you have a null pointer exception in HelloActivity on line 51, So I suggest looking there.

Comment: If you're still stumped edit your question to include the code for HelloActivity.

Comment: Yes, what that line actually tells you is the line number of the Exception: at com.example.app.HelloActivity.<init>(HelloActivity.java:51) means line 51, something is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i can say from the logcat (the code would help to make this even clearer), you wrote something in the constructor.

This is bad practice unless you exactly know what you are doing(but i think yours is just a first-timer error ;) ).
You should do everything to initialize your app in the overridden onCreate method.
Try not to create any constructor, and move everything in the onCreate method.

And remember, activities doesn't have a main function, and you can't pass arguments to them(there are [special classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to pass data between activities)

EDIT:
now that i look better at your logcat, i can tell you even more.
You are using sharedPreferences in the constructor, but when the constructor is called, the activity doesn't exist yet, so it doesn't have any prederenceManager. This is why you get a null pointer. As i said, moving everything in the onCreate method will solve your problem

Comment: Yea, this is very common for beginners. They need to read the Application Fundamentals http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html You do not instantiate activities; you start them. And, consequently, you don't provide constructors for them.